# Java JDBC query not accepted

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

Hey I'm making a little webapp and have a java file in it with a function what connects a db and fetches the data.
But I'm getting a exception anyone knows why because my query is valid if I'm right.

I use eclipse and mysql workbench.

Function:

```
import java.sql.*;

public class Functions {
    public void dbConn(String nVal, String inpVal){

        System.out.println("Running function...");

        if(nVal != null || inpVal != null){
            String sqlSerch;
            if(nVal.equals("name")){
                sqlSerch = "ID, aNaam FROM profiles WHERE naam = 'casper'";
            }else{
                sqlSerch = "naam, aNaam FROM profiles WHERE ID = " + inpVal;
            }

            //driver / db path
                final String JDBC_DRIVER = "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver";  
                final String DB_URL = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/profile";
                //DB user&password
                final String USER = "root";
                final String PASS = "";
                //declare con & sql var
                Connection conn = null;
                Statement stmt = null;
                //register jdbc driver
                try{
                    Class.forName(JDBC_DRIVER);
                    //make a connection
                    conn = DriverManager.getConnection(DB_URL,USER,PASS);
                    //SQL Statement
                    stmt = conn.createStatement();
                    String sql = "SELECT "+ sqlSerch;
                    ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(sql);

                    //Declareer variablen met data uit db
                    //int id = rs.getInt("ID");
                    String naam = rs.getString("naam");
                    String aNaam = rs.getString("aNaam");

                    System.out.println( naam + aNaam);


                    rs.close();
                    stmt.close();
                    conn.close();

                }catch(Exception e){
                    System.out.println(e);
                }


                System.out.println(" - " + nVal + " - " + inpVal);


        }
    }
}
```

exception:

> java.sql.SQLException: Column 'naam' not found.

database structure:

[image]

Thank you in advance,

Casper

Comment: you forget `rs.next()`

Comment: Where did I forgot that?
I use rs.get()
I don't need next right bc it's just one row.
Or am i wrong?

Comment: first thing is if your 'inpVal' is string then you should be using single quotes around it in sql query and yes as per @singhakash said use rs.next() but put a check before using it as...if(rs.next())

Comment: Right after "ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(sql);", insert "rs.next()"

Comment: @Casper You're wrong. Have a glance at JavaDoc: "Moves the cursor forward one row from its current position. A ResultSet cursor is initially positioned before the first row; "

Comment: `ResultSet cursor is initially positioned before the first row; the first call to the method next makes the first row the current row`-[Docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSet.html#next%28%29)

Comment: Okay, sorry I'm searching already for a hour but now it seems to be a dumb question

Comment: @singhakash I think someone should copy the first comment to the Answer box.

Comment: I still got the exception that the column naam is note found

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You branch and create your queries:

```
        if(nVal.equals("name")){
            sqlSerch = "ID, aNaam FROM profiles WHERE naam = 'casper'";
        }else{
            sqlSerch = "naam, aNaam FROM profiles WHERE ID = " + inpVal;
        }
```

Then regardless of the branch, you get your result set values:

```
        String naam = rs.getString("naam");
        String aNaam = rs.getString("aNaam");
```

But "naam" will not be in your "ID, aNaam" search.

In general, a good rule of thumb is to always return the same columns.

Comment: Yea it's true, I didn't think of it but it works now, the answer before u told me the same.
Thank you for sharing you knowledge with me

Answer (score 2):

When you receive "name" through the **nVal** parameter, you select only **ID** and **aNaam** columns.

So, if you try to get values for **naam** from that *ResultSet* you get the *Exception*.

Also, I suggest limiting the results of your query to 1, since you use the WHERE clause with **naam** and **ID**, which seem to be not unique, unless there's some constraint not included in the screenshot.

Hope this helped.

Comment: Dude you are my hero, it's true, I also need to select the column where I'm searching on
Thank you very much